# Parametrize the surface defined by the curve $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ as it rotates around the $x$-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

We know that the $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$x=\cos^3 \theta, y=\sin^3 \theta$$

verify the equation. We'd like to impose a further restriction, i.e.

$$y^2+z^2= x$$

Hence,

$$\sigma(\theta)= (\cos^3 \theta, \sin^3 \theta, \sqrt{\cos^3 \theta - \sin^{6}\theta})$$

But this is only the upper half of the solid, right? And we'd have to restrict $\theta$.

I'm truly lost.

**Is there some general guidelines as to how to find parametric equations in these cases?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is symmetry with respect to $z=0$. So, separate parametrizations

Right half $z>0$
$$\sigma(\theta)= (\cos^3 \theta, \sin^3 \theta, +\sqrt{\cos^3 \theta - \sin^{6}\theta})$$

Left half $z<0$
$$\sigma(\theta)= (\cos^3 \theta, \sin^3 \theta, -\sqrt{\cos^3 \theta - \sin^{6}\theta}).$$

At $z=0$ check for repeated roots at  golden ratio starter angles

$$ \cos \theta = \phi_1,\phi_2 $$